# photo gallery for CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

I need to integrate a photo gallery to the [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

I have a list of albums to be shown on the page. I need to have an custom icon in the CKEditor, which shows the list of albums on click of that. I need to have an option to select the album and show the album inside the page as  like [Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/demo_01.htm).

I need to be able to show the gallery between the actual content something like [Sample](http://eyecon.ro/spacegallery/).

Any Ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to program your own plugin. I don't know any plugin that do what you want. An alternative idea is to use a file browser like [PWE](http://www.neele.name/filebrowser/) to allow users to choose images in a server folder.